# Why does matplotlib's Interactive Navigation toolbar cause legend pickers to not work

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, interactive

We sometimes view a lot of system processes in comparison on a single chart.
I've created a mockup with matplotlib, as shown below.
Since there are so many data points, the legend is interactive with pickers that toggle line/artist visibility individually and whole group.

The problem that I have is that after using the Interactive Navigation zoom or pan, the interactive legend doesn't work until the same button is clicked again. If I use zoom and pan, the legend becomes completely unresponsive and requires a chart reload.

Python 3.6.0 and Matplotlib 2.0.0

```
import numpy as np
import random
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

#Generate some fake data
datalength = 60
datavariance = 25
xline = np.array(range(datalength))
y1 = np.array(range(datalength))
groups = 5 #Number of groups
members = 4 #Number of members per group
grouping = {} #Nested dictionary to hold groups and member dictionaries
for g in range(groups):
    groupmembers = {}
    for m in range(members):
        groupmembers[f'SP_{g+1}_{m+1}'] = []
    grouping[f'SP_{g+1}'] = groupmembers

#Produces a nested dictionary like:
#grouping = {'PSP_1': {'PSP_1_1':[], 'PSP_1_2':[], 'PSP_1_3':[]},
#            'PSP_2': {'PSP_2_1':[], 'PSP_2_2':[], 'PSP_2_3':[]},
#            'PSP_3': {'PSP_3_1':[], 'PSP_3_2':[], 'PSP_3_3':[]}
#            }

#Establish the figure and arrange the subplots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, facecolor='white')
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (1,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, facecolor='white')
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (2,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, facecolor='white')

# Each member is plotted in each subplot and then the artist is added to the array in the nested dictionary.
for group in grouping:
    for member in grouping[group]:
        line1 = ax1.plot(xline, y1+np.random.randint(low=0, high=datavariance, size=datalength), lw=1, label=member, marker='.')
        line2= ax2.scatter(np.random.randn(datalength)+4, y1+np.random.randint(low=0, high=datavariance, size=datalength), s=5, label=member)
        line3 = ax3.hist(np.random.randn(datalength)+4, 20, histtype='step', lw=1, label=member)
        #Dictionary entry of lines for member
        grouping[group][member].extend((line1[0], line2, line3[2]))

#Chart labeling
ax1.set_title('Process Line', fontsize=10, bbox=dict(facecolor='white'))
ax2.set_title('Process Scatter', fontsize=10, bbox=dict(facecolor='white'))
ax3.set_title('Process Histogram', fontsize=10, bbox=dict(facecolor='white'))

fig.suptitle('System Processes', fontsize=16, bbox=dict(facecolor='white'))

leghandles, leglabels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels() #Get handels and labels from subplot 1 for use in the legend.

grouplines = {} #Dictionary of lines by group
groupvisible = {} #Dictionary for visibility control
for group in grouping:
    linearray = []
    for member in grouping[group]:
        for line in grouping[group][member]:
            linearray.append(line)
    grouplines[group] = linearray #Dictionary entry of Group:array of all lines in group
    groupvisible[group] = True #Dictionary to control Group visibility
    leghandles.append(Line2D([], [], label=group, marker='_', markersize=7, lw=4, color='black')) #Array entry of non-existent lines for Group legend
    leglabels.append(group)

leghandles, leglabels = zip(*sorted(zip(leghandles, leglabels), key=operator.itemgetter(1))) #Sort legend by name
leghandlelist = list(leghandles) #Change tuple to list for inserting
leglabellist = list(leglabels) #Change tuple to list for inserting

for i in range(groups):
    leghandlelist.insert((members+2)*i, Line2D([], [], lw=.0)) #Add fake like
    leglabellist.insert((members+2)*i, ' ') #Add blank label

leghandles = tuple(leghandlelist) #Return handles to tuple
leglabels = tuple(leglabellist) #Return labels to tuple
mylegend = fig.legend(leghandles, leglabels, fancybox=True, shadow=True, loc='upper left', ncol=1, title='Process Groups')

#Associate the legend to plotted lines and set pickers on the legend item
legenditems = {}
for legendentry, plottedline in zip(mylegend.get_lines(), leghandles):
    legendentry.set_picker(5)
    legenditems[legendentry] = plottedline

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, right=0.95, top=0.90, bottom=.05, wspace=.2, hspace=.3)


def onpick(event):
    legendclick = event.artist #Legend object
    legendlabel = legendclick.get_label() #Name of selected lines or group to toggle

    #Check line visibility and toggle accordingly
    vis = not legendclick.get_visible()
    legendclick.set_visible(vis) #Toggle the clicked legend item

    if legendlabel in grouplines.keys(): #If the selected legend item is a group name
        for plottedline in grouplines[legendlabel]: #Toggle plotted lines for group members
            try: #Toggle lines and scatter points
                plottedline.set_visible(vis)
            except: #Toggle histograms
                for hi in range(len(plottedline)):
                    plottedline[hi].set_visible(vis)
        for member in grouping[legendlabel]: #Toggle legend entries for group members
            for entry in legenditems:
                if entry.get_label() == member:
                    try: #Toggle lines and scatter points
                        entry.set_visible(vis)
                    except: #Toggle histograms
                        for hi in range(len(entry)):
                            print(hi)
    else: #If a member item was selected
        for group in grouping:
            for member in grouping[group]:
                if member == legendlabel: #Toggle member lines in each chart.
                    for i in range(len(grouping[group][member])):
                        try: #Toggle lines and scatter
                            selectedline = grouping[group][member][i]
                            selectedline.set_visible(vis)
                        except: #Toggle histogram
                            for hi in range(len(grouping[group][member][i])):
                                selectedline = grouping[group][member][i][hi]
                                selectedline.set_visible(vis)

    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the complete chart becomming unresponsive. For me it behaves like you describe: As long as any of the interactive tools is active, the pick event is not triggered, but as soon as you deactivate the tool, it becomes responsive again. This is usually desired: You do not want to trigger a pick event while clicking in your plot for zooming or panning. Or the other way around: How would you distinguish between a click for zooming from a click for picking?

Comment: Very true, I never thought about that.
My pickers are all on the legend, but they could have been in the graph itself.

To bad you couldn't load the chart.  For being a beginner, I'm proud of what I was able to accomplish.

I just have to be careful to not use zoom and pan (though I hardly ever use pan anyway), and then deactivate the tool.

As this appears needed and intentional function, I'll except that as the answer.